# JQuery animate not animating 'bottom' property

Tags: jquery, html, animation, css-animations

Not sure what's missing but I'm not seeing any animation, thou it sets correctly the attributes on "complete":

```
$(window).load ->
    $('#mc_embed_signup').animate { bottom: '+=50px' },
      duration: 2000
      easing: 'linear'
      complete: ->
        $('#mc_embed_signup').css 'bottom', '0px'
        $('#mc_embed_signup').css 'position', 'fixed'
        return
```

This is my html:

```
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
  ...
</div>
```

Styles (sass file):

```
#mc_embed_signup
  position: relative
  bottom: -50px
  background: #A2A2A2
  width: 100%
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you fix your syntax errors this works as expected. You've got a bunch of missing commas and parenthesis. See the [`jQuery.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) documentation for the different syntaxes.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#mc_embed_signup').animate(
    { bottom: '50px' },
    { 
      duration: 2000,
      easing: 'linear',
      complete: function() {
        $('#mc_embed_signup').css('bottom', '0px');
        $('#mc_embed_signup').css('position', 'fixed');
      }
    }
  );
});
```

```css
#mc_embed_signup {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -50px;
  background: #A2A2A2;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

This is my html:

<div id="mc_embed_signup">
  ....
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @dave, but i forgot to mention I'm using coffeescript (that's why you find "missing" commas and parenthesis) and sass for the styles.
Still, I'll recheck the syntax.

Comment: Well I am no CoffeeScript expert but I am pretty sure you still need the curly brackets before `duration` and after `complete`.